# convert a zip file to MSI file/EXE file/windows installation file

Tags: c#

I want to convert a zip file to MSI file/EXE file/windows installation file to install in remote computers in the network.

Up to now, I can make a zip file with user selected executable files and related support files etc. using the following C# code.

---

```
private void btnPackaging_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // make sure there are files to zip
        if (listBox1.Items.Count < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There are no files queued for the zip operation", "Empty File Set");
            return;
        }

        // make sure there is a destination defined
        if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No destination file has been defined.", "Save To Empty");
            return;
        }

        label3.Visible = true;
        label3.Refresh();

        // name the zip file whatever the folder is named
        // by splitting the file path to get the folder name
        string[] sTemp = textBox1.Text.Split('\\');
        string sZipFileName = sTemp[sTemp.Length - 1].ToString();

        // check to see if zipped file already exists
        // user may rename it in the text box if it does.
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(textBox1.Text + "\\" + sZipFileName + ".zip");
        if (fi.Exists)
        {
            // move it to the folder
            try
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("The file " + sZipFileName + " already exists. ");
                sb.Append("You may rename it in the save to text box.");
                MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString(), "Existing File Name");
                textBox1.Focus();
                return;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Rename the file or select a new location.", "File Error");
                return;
            }
        }


        // Check for the existence of the target folder and
        // create it if it does not exist
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(textBox1.Text + "\\TempZipFile\\"))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(textBox1.Text + "\\TempZipFile\\");
        }

        // Set up a string to hold the path to the temp folder
        string sTargetFolderPath = (textBox1.Text + "\\TempZipFile\\");

        // Process the files and move each into the target folder
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            string filePath = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
            FileInfo fi2 = new FileInfo(filePath);
            if (fi2.Exists)
            {
                // move it to the folder
                try
                {
                    fi2.CopyTo(sTargetFolderPath + fi2.Name, true);
                }
                catch
                {
                    // clean up if the operation failed
                    System.IO.Directory.Delete(sTargetFolderPath);
                    MessageBox.Show("Could not copy files to temp folder.", "File Error");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }


        // zip up the files
        try
        {
            label3.Visible = true;
            label3.Refresh();

            string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(sTargetFolderPath);

            // Zip up the files - From SharpZipLib Demo Code
            using (ZipOutputStream s = new ZipOutputStream(File.Create(textBox1.Text + "\\" + sZipFileName + ".zip")))
            {
                s.SetLevel(9); // 0-9, 9 being the highest level of compression

                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

                foreach (string file in filenames)
                {

                    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(file));

                    entry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    s.PutNextEntry(entry);

                    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(file))
                    {
                        int sourceBytes;
                        do
                        {
                            sourceBytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            s.Write(buffer, 0, sourceBytes);

                        } while (sourceBytes > 0);
                    }
                }
                s.Finish();
                s.Close();
            }

            // remove the progress bar
            label3.Visible = false;

            // clean up files by deleting the temp folder and its content
            System.IO.Directory.Delete(textBox1.Text + "\\TempZipFile\\", true);

            // Notify user
            MessageBox.Show("Zip file " + textBox1.Text + " created.");

            // empty everything
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Zip Operation Error");
        }
        this.Dispose();
    }
```

---

I don't have any idea, how to develop C# code to convert zip file into MSI file/EXE file/windows installation file.

Please help me, if anybody have an idea to solve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Maybe you want self-extracting zip file?

Comment: Why can't you use self-extracting archive or already existing installer?

Comment: I am trying to develop my code for this process.

Comment: If i want use existing installers, how can i use them in background without direct user interaction?

Comment: @brat4 Can we know your project goal?

Comment: @Mr.MDD I am developing a tool for Automated Deployment. The automated deployment tool will run on a server and perform two basic tasks:
• Package applications (executables, libraries, configuration files) from the server and all the client machines into one entity in the server.
• Deploy applications (executables, libraries, configuration files) into the server and all the client machines from the single entity in the server.

The User Interface in the tool will be able to receive the configuration (IP address, options, etc) of the platform from the user, for packaging and deployment.

Comment: Why no answers??